# Cant import pynput on macos Monterey 12.1

Tags: python, attributeerror, pynput

When I try to run, I keep getting this error. I've tried downgrading to `pyobjc 7.3` and it still gives me the same error. What could be the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeremyparker/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pynput
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 70, in backend
    return importlib.import_module('._' + module, package)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/_darwin.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pynput._util.darwin import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynput/_util/darwin.py", line 60, in <module>
    OBJC.PyObjCObject_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x2055dbc80, PyObjCObject_New): symbol not found
```